# How to add label to a FeatureLayout using object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

How can I add a label to a FeatureLayout using an object? I don't have just one featureLayout, so I created an object with multiple layouts like this

```
const layersByYears = [ 
    { year: 1918, layers: [ 
        { layerID: "1", opacity: 1.0, name: "name1", featureLayer: null,labelingInfo: labelClass },
        { layerID: "2", opacity: 1.0, name: "name2", featureLayer: null },
        { layerID: "3", opacity: 1.0, name: "name3", featureLayer: null },
        { layerID: "4", opacity: 1.0, name: "name4", featureLayer: null }
    ] },...]
```

Then I have variable labelClass like this:

```
const labelClass = {
    symbol: {
        type: "text",  // autocasts as new TextSymbol()
        color: "black",
        font: {  // autocast as new Font()
          family: "Playfair Display",
          size: 12,
          weight: "bold"
        }
      },
      labelPlacement: "above-center",
      labelExpressionInfo: {
        expression: "42"        
      }
}
```

And last I created layer like this:

```
const createFL = (layer) => {
        if(layer.featureLayer !== null && layer.featureLayer !== undefined)
            return;
        layer.featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({ 
            portalItem: {
                id: layer.layerID,
                opacity: layer.opacity !== undefined ? layer.opacity : 1.0,
                visible: false,
            }, labelingInfo: layer.labelingInfo 
     })
    }
```

I am not sure what I have wrong. I can see the layer from ArcGis online but I cannot see the labels in my graph. The graph is simple point graph. The *labelClass* variable is declared prior to *layersByYears* variable.

Comment: `labelingInfo` property expects and array of `LabelClass`, you are just passing a single one. Try `labelingInfo: [layer.labelingInfo]`.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you.